# How to pick all the firsts occurrences of data when iterating through xsl:for-each

Tags: xml, xslt

In XSLT I want to iterate through one node of each country. I dont know how many countries are in the XML...

With that file:

```
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>            
        <country>USA</country>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <country>UK</country>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Greatest Hits</title>
        <country>USA</country>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Greatest Hits</title>
        <country>UK</country>
    </cd>

    <cd>
        <title>Greatest Hits</title>
        <country>FIN</country>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>SUPER Greatest Hits</title>
        <country>SPA</country>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Greatest Hits2</title>
        <country>FIN</country>
    </cd>
 </catalog>
```

I need to iterate by the first node of USA, UK, FIN and SPA. I only want to iterate through the first of each country, and forget addional nodes.

With something like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd[country='USA']">
  <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
```

I have to know what is the name of each country in the XSLT... so it will not work for me...

Comment: Assuming you are using XSLT 1.0, see: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html (which the answer given below attempts to implement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best solution for this problem is using Keys and operator | of xpath.

First of all create a key through the field you wanna iterate:

```
<xsl:key name="countries" match="catalog/cd" use="country" />
```

Then i iterate by all the CD, but with one special condition:

```
<xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd[count(.| key('countries', country)[1])=1 ]">
```

Operator **|** is the UNION operator in xpath.
UNION of one node with himself results in a single node, not 2. THAT is really important for the solution.

**.|key('countries', country)[1]**   means that if the current node you are iterating for UNION the first accurrence of that country in all the document are the same node, then we want to iterate through it. Else we dont!

Comment: This is a good approach, but you have a typo in the `match` portion of your `key` - remove the `]`.  There's also a typo in your question (`<catalog>` should be `</catalog>`) at the end.  It might also be helpful for future users if you posted a working example of the XSLT, which you're pretty close to here.

Comment: Answering your own question is a good thing, but I agree with Dan; make it a complete answer, showing a complete XSLT stylesheet, and the complete output.